# how to correctly highlight words using original javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to highlight all words from search text using other [people's code](http://jsbin.com/ebucaz/108/edit?html,js,output)

The JavaScript code is here:

```
var s = document.querySelector('input[type="search"]'),
    p = document.querySelector('p'),
    find = function(){
        var words = p.innerText.split(' '),
            i = words.length,
            word = '';

        while(--i) {
            word = words[i];
            if(word.toLowerCase() == s.value.toLowerCase()){
                words[i] = '<span class="highlight">' + word + "</span>";
            }
            else{

            }   
        }

        p.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
    }

s.addEventListener('keydown', find , false);
s.addEventListener('keyup', find , false);
```

However, in this code if want to search some words end with '.', it won't give me correct content. I figure out, it is caused by `var words = p.innerText.split(' ')` however if I used `split(/\b(\w+)\b/g)` it will cause the extra space. 
  How can I use right regular expression to accomplish this using original js?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it in one shot, what you would need to do is first split `p.innerHTML` using an empty space as you've already done above, but utilize another function to differentiate between the word and the punctuation. I've written a function that you may find useful to solve your problem. Run the code to see sample outputs.

```js
//  This function will return the HTML for highlighting the word if successful
//  Othewise, it will return undefined

function highlightWord(originalWord, newWord) {
  let re = /[.,:;]+$/
  if (originalWord === newWord) {
    return `<span class="highlight">${newWord}</span>`
  } else if (re.test(newWord)) {
    let contains = new RegExp(`^${originalWord}`);
    let nonContainingPart = new RegExp(`[^${originalWord}]+`)
    if (contains.test(newWord)) {
      let word = newWord.match(contains)
      let punctuation = newWord.match(nonContainingPart)
      // Sample output of 'word' and 'punctuation'
      //word = [ 'book', index: 0, input: 'book...' ]
      //punctuation = [ '...', index: 4, input: 'book...' ]
      return `<span class="highlight">${word}</span>${punctuation}`
    }
  }
}

console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book.'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book...'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book:'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book;'))
console.log(highlightWord('booker', 'book;'))
console.log(highlightWord('books', 'book;'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'booka'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book-'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book_'))
console.log(highlightWord('book', 'book~'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes a lot sences